# C# Universal app for Windows 10 'System.Exception'

Tags: c#, exception, gif, encode, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to develop app which encode images to gif. I found this code, but it throws an System.Exception after encode.SetPixelData(...

```
readonly List<byte[]> frames = new List<byte[]>();
    public IAsyncInfo GenerateAsync(StorageFile file)
    {
        return AsyncInfo.Run(async ctx =>
        {
            var outStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.GifEncoderId, outStream);

            for (int i = 0; i < frames.Count; i++)
            {
                var pixels = frames[i];

                encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                                     frameWidth, frameHeight,
                                     92.0, 92.0,
                                     pixels);


                if (i < frames.Count - 1)
                    await encoder.GoToNextFrameAsync();
            }

            await encoder.FlushAsync();
            outStream.Dispose();
        });
    }
```

It is because of lack of memory? 
How to fix this exception?

Thanks for help:)

Comment: What does the innerexception say?

Comment: Trap the exception and examine it's details in the debugger. This will tell you what's wrong and help you work out how to fix the problem.

Comment: _The allocated buffer is insufficient. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F8C)_
This is my error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824873/the-buffer-allocated-is-insufficient-exception-while-calling-bitmapencoder-set

This might help you!